# Subtrair datas em PHP

Tags: php, data

Eu estou com um projeto em que preciso mudar uma informação de semana a semana.

Existe alguma função automatizada do PHP que me possa ajudar a subtrair a data de hoje por uma data base que eu definí. Por exemplo:

```
$datadehoje = (int)date("d/m/Y");
$database = (int)date("15/07/2018");
$resultado = $datadehoje - $database;
```

O código acima está escrito de maneira errada mas é para exemplificar mais ou menos o que eu queria. O projeto irá dispor informação durante meses e não queria ter que criar um algoritmo próprio para isso.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 5):

Não tem como converter uma data em `int` e obter algo significativo. Tem que fazer a diferença usando o próprio tipo de data para obter um resultado significativo, que será um intervalo de datas. Depois pode obter a quantidade de dias que é um texto, se quiser pode converter esse texto para número se for fazer contas com ele.

```
$database = date_create('2018-07-15');
$datadehoje = date_create();
$resultado = date_diff($database, $datadehoje);
echo date_interval_format($resultado, '%a');
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futur](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Date/Subtraction.php)a.

- [`date_create()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-create.php)
- [`date_diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php)
- [`date_interval_format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-interval-format.php)

Answer (score 2):

Uma das formas de se fazer uma operação com datas em `PHP` é:

```
// a partir da data de hoje
echo date("d/m/Y",strtotime(date("Y-m-d")."+12 month"));

// a partir de outras datas
echo date("d/m/Y",strtotime(date("Y-m-d",strtotime($data_de_referencia))."-12 month"));
```

> [Referência **date()**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php)
>
> [Referência **strtotime()**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtotime.php)